# Meaning of "as wild of... as possible"

Tags: meaning, grammar

Here is the sentence:

> "The goal of my position is to have as wild of bears as possible in this park"

What does *"wild of bears"* mean?

I know the form "as [adjective/adverb] as possible" like in "as soon as possible" and "as clean as possible".

But it seems neither forms apply to the quote above.

What I intuitively understood from context is that "the more wild and less habituated to humans the bears are, the better".

But I would have a deeper understanding if someone could provide more examples of expressions in form **as ... of ... as possible**.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the sentence is intended to be 'bears as wild as possible'.

Comment: @WeatherVane So for instance *"to have as tall of trees as possible in this park"* is correct grammar?

Comment: Similarly, 'trees as tall as possible'.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the most idiomatic of word orders, but it's legit by most measures, and might be used as a form of emphasis.

Comment: Seems to work better with singular and mass nouns, though—as big of a mess as possible—as wild of a bear as possible—as tall of a tree as possible.

Comment: As Weather Vane suggests it is a contraction of: As wild *a version of*  bears as possible.

Comment: "As wild of bears as possible" isn't used in the UK. Neither is "as big of a deal". (Gracious me! Look away, children!)

Comment: I would rephrase it as 'to let the bears in this park be as wild as possible'. The original is very clumsy.